# JavaScript global timer fired by multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two jQuery sliders on a page. I would like to fire an event when the user has set both of them. I define "set" as "when both sliders have been idle for 3 seconds".

Can I do something like this, or is it bad practice to create a global variable like this / are there any other problems with the code?

```
var globalTimer = null;
function myEvent() { 
    alert('Both sliders are set!');
}

$("#slider-1").slider({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
     clearTimeout(globalTimer);
     globalTimer = setTimeout(myEvent, 3000);       
  }
});
$("#slider-2").slider({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
     clearTimeout(globalTimer);
     globalTimer = setTimeout(myEvent, 3000);       
  }
});
```

Comment: Another problem is copy pasted code, you could use `$("#slider-1,#slider-2").slider( ... )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the global variable. Your code has to be contained within a [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) block, so that the `.slider` method is called when the document is ready.

That already creates a closure, in which you can declare the `globalTimer` variable.

When the `.slider` plugin is well-defined <sup>See bottom</sup>, you can combine the selectors, and use `.slider(..)` to activate the plugin for both elements:

```
$(function() {
    var globalTimer = null;
    function myEvent() { 
        alert('Both sliders are set!');
    }

    $("#slider-1, #slider-2").slider({
      stop: function(event, ui) {
         clearTimeout(globalTimer);
         globalTimer = setTimeout(myEvent, 3000);       
      }
    });
});
```

In jQuery, plugins should be defined as shown below. That allows a single plugin call to apply functionality on a all elements which match the selector. This effectively reduces code:

```
$.fn.plugin = function() {
    // this = jQuery object
    return this.each(function() {
        // function logic, this = DOM element
    });
};
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! Yes, my code's already wrapped in `$(document).ready`, and I'm using the jQuery UI slider, so it should be well-defined. I wanted to check it was OK to use a "global" variable within the closure, because I know "globals" are just frowned upon generally as bad practice, but I couldn't see another way to do it here.

Comment: @Richard Globals are frowned upon, because they may conflict with other scripts. A variable within a closure will never cause problems at another script, because a local scope variable is not visible outside the closure.